# Why does PostgreSQL string less than work differently between 9.1 and 9.3?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 PostgreSQL databases. The first one is version 9.1, and the second is version 9.3. They are configured the same way (including setting `standard_conforming_strings=off`). The following query returns one result on the version 9.1 database but returns nothing when run on the 9.3 database. Why?

`select 'WORKS' where 'test.123' < 'test/';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your databases may have different collation settings, which affects sort order. [Check your collation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29943/how-to-determine-the-collation-of-a-table-in-postgresql) with:

```
select datname, datcollate from pg_database;
```

If that's the case, you'll [need to drop and recreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420925/change-database-collation-ctype-in-postgresql) your 9.3 database with a collation matching your 9.1 copy.

Comment: Thanks. IT creates databases with a scripted install so I was assuming that this couldn't be the case. Well, thanks again.